# downloading file over http not working but over https working fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, https, download

I have the following scenario downloading a file form sever:

- I am trying to download many files from server over HTTP (but *not SSL*) in an ASP.NET page, but one of the files is not downloading; it returns an error: `operation timeout`.
- When I try to download this file over HTTPS, it works well.
- I tried to download the file using other software using plain HTTP and I received the same error message.

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Comment: What's wrong with downloading via HTTPS, then?

Comment: Perhaps you have the s3 service configured to only allow HTTPS connections, besides whats wrong with using HTTPS?

Comment: there is no wrong .. but i think in http the requests is transferred faster than https .. although i want to know the reason of this issue

Comment: Once the connection is set up, HTTPS and HTTP are virtually the same speed; the session encryption used is not generally a bottleneck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if (The file is executable file )
>
> May be because the web
>   server for some EXE files resides on
>   doesn't send a
>   Content-Length header. If this header
>   is absent, the only way you can
>   determine if the download is complete
>   is "when the bytes stop coming", i.e.
>   the TCP/IP connection is closed or
>   times out. If the connection quality
>   is low, this may very well happen
>   prematurely.
>
> But why this not happened in Https?
>   Thats because http has bigger waiting
>   time and smaller receiving time. https
>   on the other hand has smaller waiting
>   time and bigger receiving time.
>
> The http port on the shared hosting
>   server is more busy, thus a request
>   stays longer in the queue until is
>   accepted by the server.
>
> On the https port there is less
>   traffic on the server so the request
>   is serviced faster.